# Angular material input pattern add white space

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I have problem to validate white space in angular 7 input pattern.

```
<form #f="ngForm">
    <mat-form-field floatLabel="always">
        <input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+" required matInput name="folderName">
    </mat-form-field>
    </form>
<button mat-raised-button [disabled]="!f.valid">Create</button>
```

I tried with:

- pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+"  Create button get disabled first time I add space
- pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_- ]+"   I get message "Invalid regular expression" from angular. Here is a white space after '-' in pattern and that is invalid.

Where I am wrong ?

Comment: `-` must be at the end: `pattern="[\w\s-]+"`. The issue is not with adding whitespace, but with using a hyphen inside a character class.

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved my problem.